# Windows 10 laptop is filtering out any recorded music on any microphone

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, music, audio-recording

My Windows 10 Alienware laptop is filtering out any sound that isn't "voice-like" when recording on any microphone. I'm confident that this is some sort of noise-blocking enhancement feature that helps on video conferencing calls but I need to figure out how to turn it off for recording guitar.

The filter seems to affect any type of non-voice sounds, whether its guitar (direct via amp or just ambient room noise) or even just whistling. I have tried using the built-in microphone, an external USB microphone, and even my guitar amp's USB connection (which appears to Windows as a 'microphone'), and all are equally affected.

I've tried recording using the windows sound recorder, Audacity, and also CakeWalk with similar effects.

I can't seem to find the relevant setting anywhere, and I'm not sure if its a special application that's installed that's doing the filtering or if there's a hidden Windows 10 setting somewhere.

On another Dell laptop (different hardware), also running Windows 10, I can record any music just fine.

Here are the microphone properties:

[image: microphone properties]

Here are the sound devices in the Device Manager:

[image: Device manager sound devices]

**Note**: Bluetooth headset name containing personal information has been obscured.

I have tried disabling all the "Intel smart sound" devices and they seemed to have no effect.

I tried installing the "Realtek audio console" program, but there are no settings for recording, except for audio volume (screenshot shown below).

[image: Realtek audio console]

---

**Update**: I can confirm that by running a Windows 10 virtual machine (via VMWare Workstation Pro) and passing through my USB mic, that the filtering issue is **not** present in the VM. This seems to confirm the issue is with software or drivers and not a mic or other hardware problem.

Comment: A friend of mine had a similar problem - was digging for hours in various control panel settings, ended up reinstalling windows, and it didn't help. Finally, he found that it was so simple; The setting here: Windows settings app > System > Sound > [Select your device under "Input"] > Audio enhancements > [select "Off"]. I guess you already looked here, but just in case.

Comment: I did, but appreciate the suggestion!

Comment: Try these: 1) check for nvidia rtx voice in startup, and disable it  2) close any programs running in background, especially teams, zoom, equalizer ecc. 3) Start in safe mode and see if it changes  4) create a new user and don't enable any startup apps.  -- It could be an app or an app driver messing with the settings

Comment: Also, check if you nvidia hd audio driver has any options

Comment: @1NN Thank you for the ideas. Results are:  1) It's not in there.  2) I don't see any running.  3) In safe mode, I can't record or listen to any audio unfortunately.  4) I tried this and did not have success either.  5) I don't see any options for the Nvidia HD audio driver.  Do you now where I should be looking?

Comment: looks like nvidia HD only affects output. Have you checked for dell optimizer? https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/dell-optimizer/dell-optimizer-4.1.3_ug/optimizing-audio?guid=guid-bb1ed2e1-1fda-452b-bca5-49993d33c497&lang=en-us  Then, it's  a long shot but you should check your Bios/ UEFI too

Comment: It appears dell optimizer is not compatible with my alienware laptop. Or at least that is what the dell support website says.

Comment: 1)What is your dell Alienware model? 2)realtek audio console has advanced settings section, anything regarding microphone/voice/filter? 3)does your start menu or control panel show anything for realtek? 4)can you list your realtek, realtek USB, & USB plug & play driver versions, hardware id, & events tab in device manager?

Comment: [Your Alienware command center pic in a comment](https://i.imgur.com/e7gOQyN.png) on an answer shows what looks like a Dolby Atmos button on the side. [Command center documentation](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/alienware-command-center/docs) advises that opens Atmos app, [pictures online seem to imply that might has a voice section](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/RkfLhQiRpNw/maxresdefault.jpg) so maybe if you got that app it would let you change some hardware voice filtering you can't otherwise at the moment

Comment: I see you have ASIO4ALL which seems to legit be designed to circumvent default sound stuff. If possible consider uninstalling that then see if microphone works properly

Comment: I installed ASIO4ALL in hopes of getting around the issue :)  But I will uninstall it to see if it helps.  I also got the "dolby access" program and looked in the voice section, but there's nothing to configure unfortunately: https://i.imgur.com/haDHIeh.png

Comment: Dolby access only seems to do with output so we can probably ignore that app: https://kb.dolby.com/access?kid=ka64u000000GoP2AAK&articletype=FAQ&articlecategory=Dolby_Access__c

Comment: What happens if you use the microphone from within a VM ? Also, uninstalling and reinstalling sound drivers could help.

Comment: @1NN Wow, what a great idea.  I fired up a win10 VM in VMWare Pro and it works!  I suppose this confirms its definitely a software issue.  

I did try reinstalling sound drivers previously, which resulted in no change.

Comment: Good to know. At least you have a workaround. Other thing to check: Did you ever set up your microphone for speech recognition? It's in Settings -> Language -> Speech. Also, it could be Cortana messing up things: better disable it.

Comment: I have not set that up.  As far as I can tell its not enabled.

Comment: Never heard back on these items from a previous comment: 1)What is your dell Alienware model? 3)does your start menu or control panel show anything for realtek? 4)can you list your realtek, realtek USB, & USB plug & play driver versions, hardware id (under Details tab), & Events (tab) in device manager? https://imgur.com/a/Wcfemgl

Comment: @gregg Alienware m15 R7.  Yes, since having this problem I installed "realtek audio console", but there are no mic settings other than volume/mute.  Realtek audio driver: 6.0.9586.1, Realtek USB audio: 6.3.9600.2330, USB pnp Audio: 10.0.19041.3636

Comment: Indeed you have the latest realtek per dells page for this laptop model. 1) Can you share some screenshots of the realtek audio console 'device advanced settings' section? 2) Any idea what the realteak USB & USB is powering? Guessing its just output likely from a docking station & USB PnP is the guitar amp you mentioned

Comment: Last ditch idea: I've seen some odd things with Realtek on Dell equipment. If driver updates don't solve two things I've done: 1) in device manager, right-click Realtek Audio then uninstall devic, reboot. 2)If that didn't work try to uninstall again in device manager, but [check the box to delete driver](https://networking.grok.lsu.edu/image/50315.png), reboot, this breaks audio until windows auto installs a driver, but have the driver ready to install again

Comment: Another interesting tidbit: audio controller for this model is Realtek ALC3254. Someone mentioned another model ALC256 has a quirk where 'Intel Smart Sound Technology' controls the microphone, but everything else is controlled by Realtek. I'd uninstall 'Intel Smart Sound Technology' digital microphone & maybe USB then  reboot to see if it helps. Please provide those hardware ID's for Realtek Audio & Intel Smart Microphone. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=279424&start=47 https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201251

Comment: @gregg You found it!  Everything works great if I open that app and turn off AI noise reduction. If you want to write up an answer I'll gladly choose it.

Comment: Hooray! I've added a lame answer for the moment as I'm currently busy. I'll edit it in the future to elaborate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intel Smart (or IntelliGo) app likely controls the microphone for this chipset (ADL-P PCH [CPU=i7-12700H]) or audio controller (Realtek ALC3254) in your [Alienware m15 R7](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/alienware-m15-r7-gaming-laptop/overview). I'll edit and expand on this answer in the future. Likely from previous comments (like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1825226/windows-10-laptop-is-filtering-out-any-recorded-music-on-any-microphone#comment2878295_1825226)) on the original answer.

It would be good if OP to screenshot which app & setting fixed their issue to help future people who stumble across this page with the same issue.

Comment: Here is the IntelliGo Neptune app which finally allowed me to turn off the noise reduction: https://i.imgur.com/TTqazTw.png

Answer (score 3):

Not sure it works but it's too long for a comment:

- Open "Alienware Command Center"
- "Fusion" tab
- "Sound Settings"(click on loudspeaker)
- In the "Audio Profiles" Section, either choose the appropriate profile, or create a new profile and disable all effects.

Comment: Unfortunately, my alienware command center doesn't seem to have that option under the Fusion tab.  https://i.imgur.com/e7gOQyN.png

Comment: After clicking Fusion tab, on left side under power cord is a button where it looks like two half circles (Dolby Atmos logo), click that. Look for voice, microphone, or equalizer

Comment: https://youtu.be/YAXeKXqlHaI&t=17m42s https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/alienware-command-center/docs

Comment: @KyleL chck out greggs comments here above

Comment: @gregg My alienware command center is missing the audio section, unfortunately.  Not sure if they removed it since 2021, or if my laptop doesn't support it

Comment: @KyleL as Gregg pointed out, in YOUR Screenshot, the audio tab has the Double-D dolby atmos logo, it's the fourth tab on the left hand side. See what's in there

Comment: @1NN thanks, yes I checked this as well.  There are no microphone settings in there, only dolby speaker/headphone settings

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the double-D area just to humor us? The youtube video did say 2021 & had a speaker symbol on left buttons, but did have a Recording tab: https://imgur.com/a/uBbHJT7

Comment: @gregg Absolutely! https://i.imgur.com/pBI7KSy.png  Here is what the dolby app screen looks like: https://i.imgur.com/Njpvesb.png

Answer (score 3):

Your problem might be
[Audio Ducking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ducking).

This is a dynamic audio processing technique that enables
the automatic adjustment of audio levels between different
audio sources on Windows.

The article
[What is Audio Ducking and How to Do It in Music Production](https://www.izotope.com/en/learn/what-is-audio-ducking.html)
has this definition:

> Audio ducking is simply the process of compressing (or “ducking down”) the volume of an audio signal whenever another audio signal goes above a certain threshold. When used gently, this technique allows you to get more clarity from both audio signals.

To disable it in Windows :

- Run *Control Panel > Sound*
- Position to the Communications tab

  [image]
- Select the preferred option, which is perhaps "Do nothing"
- Click OK.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately it was already set to "do nothing".

Comment: Do you mean that you wish to record both the microphone and the speaker? A solution like [this](https://recorder.easeus.com/screen-recording-tips/record-system-audio-and-microphone-at-the-same-time.html)?

Comment: no just the microphone.  I'm not having the computer produce any sounds at the same time, just attempting to record.

Comment: Which app is used for recording ?

Comment: I have tried audacity, windows voice recorder, and cakewalk.  Is there another one I should try instead?

Comment: No, these are probably enough. See if these [3 methods](https://robots.net/tech/how-to-turn-off-noise-cancellation-on-windows-10/) relate to the problem. Can you manage to record better while booting in Safe mode, and if yes, does this still happen?

Comment: I can't get any sound to play or record while in safe mode, unfortunately

Comment: Yes, I was skeptical about it, since third-party drivers are disabled in this mode. Have you tried to ask Alienware Support? Does the other Dell laptop use the same microphone device and driver?

Comment: I have not yet.  I haven't had a lot of luck with their support in the past, but will probably try if nothing pans out here.  The other dell laptop is an older generation (and not alienware), so different motherboard, drivers, etc.

Comment: Support has answered for me. Try perhaps the sound troubleshooter in *Settings > System > Sound*.

Comment: Thank you for the info.  I tried the "Recording audio" troubshooter in Windows.  It says it fixed an issue with "audio enhancements", but I don't see any change in behavior.

Comment: I don't know what's going wrong, as it least one of the answers should have worked. In case that something has gone wrong with Windows, I suggest doing [Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) which will set Windows to a coherent state. This is the same as doing a major Windows upgrade and will conserve apps and setting, but do take precautions.

Comment: I did contact dell support.  They walked through a bunch of things to try and nothing fixed it.  At the end they basically told me its a windows problem and they can't help.

Comment: Repair Install seems like the only thing left to do.

Answer (score 1):

Since it sounds like a very good noise-cancellation technology, on a gaming laptop - It sounds like it's Nvidia's.

I'd check if "**Nvidia Broadcast App**" or "**Nvidia RTX Voice**" are installed on said computer. If so, open them, and disable the noise-cancellation feature.

---

**Edit**: If said apps aren't present on the device, could you share a screenshot of appwiz.cpl, for us to see a list of installed applications?

Comment: I don't seem to have those apps, or at least don't see them installed.  Here is the my full list as requested: https://i.imgur.com/h1wqd12.png

Comment: After seeing your post, I looked further into these apps.  It appears they create a virtual microphone device that you have to select to get their filtering effects.  Definitely a cool feature, but not something I was using.